# What is meant by "smooth" instantons, and is there a constraint on the winding number of $E_8$ instantons?

Tags: string-theory, compactification, instantons

In the paper, ``[Comments on String Dynamics in Six Dimensions](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9603003)" ([arXiv:hep-th/9603003](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9603003)) by Seiberg and Witten, there is a sentence on page 8 (section 3) which reads

> classically, smooth $E_8$ instantons with $n = 1, 2,$ or $3$ do not exist.

$n$ refers to the winding number (corresponding to the embedding of $SU(2$) in $E_8$).

My question is: why do the winding numbers $n = 1, 2, 3$ not exist? What is meant by smooth instantons?

Also, is the $n \neq \{1,2,3\}$ constraint valid for K3 compactifications or is it more general?

Comment: Do you have a reason to suspect it means something other than the general notion of an instanton in a gauge theory with gauge group $G=E_8$?

Comment: No, I do not. But what are smooth instantons and why don't they exist for $n = 1, 2, 3$?